# How would you create a database table dynamically in code with ASP.NET Core EF

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I built a configuration UI, where the customer would enter their own SQL settings and saves the connection string.

How would you create a database table from the controller using ASP.Net Core with EF?  It works with no problem doing "Add-Migration {name}", then "Update-Database" through the package manager console.

ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : 
        base(options)
    {
    
    }

    public DbSet<ManagedDomain> ManagedDomains { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Please don't LOL at me, but out of desperation, I'm literally laughing at myself when I tried, figuring it wouldn't work and of course it didn't...

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost("CreateDbTable")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateDbTable([FromServices] ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{

    try
    {
        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        return Ok(new mResponse { Status = "success", Message = "Wish it would workie!!!" });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Ok(new mResponse { Status = "failed", Message = ex.Message });
    }


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `dbContext.Database.Migrate();` code means the ef command update-database. Details, you could check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#command-line-tools).

The EF api doesn't contain the add migration command method, since the add-migration command will firstly build the project and then generate the migrate class based on your build well project.

Besides, we don't suggest you do the migrate inside the production environment, since modifying the database may delete previous table which caused data loss.